# What is the real formula for Hill Cipher? (Book Correction)

Tags: cryptography

My book "Cryptography Theory and Practice" by Douglas R. Stinson states that the formulas for encrypting and decrypting on page 19 are follow:

> For a key $K$, we define
>
> $$e_K(x)=xK$$
>
> and
>
> $$d_K(y)=yK^{-1}$$
>
> Where all operations are performed in $\mathbb{z}_{26}$

but in all sources like wikipedia, journal, etc state that the formula is:

> $$e_K(x)=Kx$$
>
> and
>
> $$d_K(y)=K^{-1}y$$

Which one is correct?
$K$ is a matrix, and i know matrices aren't commutative. Thus, those formulas are different.

I've tried encrypted and decrypted with the first formula, i got different result. But when i tried the second formula, i got the same result.

Is that mean the book is wrong or what?

Please help me to clear this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your book has adopted row vector convention. That is your $x$ is a row vector.

Wikipedia has adopted column vector convention. That is $x$ is a column vector.

To change one convention to the other convention, you just have to transpose everything, note that $$(xK)^T=K^Tx^T$$ where $x$ is a row vector here.

You have to fix and state your convention clearly.

Comment: Hi Siong thanks for the answer. Btw is an italic T stands for Transpose? But there is no transpose on my book

Comment: yes, that is because the book is consistent that they just use the row convention throughout.

Comment: Here is 1 example on page 19: encrypt "ju" with the key $$K=\begin{pmatrix} 11 & 8\\ 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$$ so $$(9,20)\begin{pmatrix} 11 & 8\\ 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix}=(99+60,72+140)=(3,4)$$ and the term $(a,b)$ is a column vector i guess?

Comment: $(a,b)$ is a row vector since it is a row. $\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\end{bmatrix}$ is a column vector.

Comment: And if we want to encrypt "ju" with the formula that stated by wikipedia and another journals, it supposed to be $$\begin{pmatrix} 11 & 8\\ 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix}(9,20)$$ which gives me the answer $(25,11)$

Comment: ah, sorry. Yes it's a row vector.

Comment: Let $K_B$ be the matrix in your book, then the corresponding matrix in the wikipedia should be $K_W=K_B^T$. Also remember that the matrix size must be compatible to perform marix multiplication.

Comment: But still gives me different result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105536/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-user516076).